# SqlKata - square brackets in request

Tags: c#, sql, .net, postgresql, sqlkata

how to enclose 1 in square brackets?
sklkata at compilation replaces them with quotes

```
.SelectRaw("(array_agg([any.date] order by [any.date] desc))[1] AS [any]")
```

Answer (score 0):

This drove me crazy for a long time, I give you the answer and also, an extra hint.

The only way to avoid it is escaping the characters you don't want to be replaced (clearly the compiler is doing an extra step, so it's not technically 'raw')

`.SelectRaw(@"(array_agg(\[any.date\] order by \[any.date\] desc))[1] AS \[any\]")`

Also, in some cases I noticed it still replaces more stuff and it's related to the compiler. I had a couple of cases where the only way to make it work was using the specific compiler instruction:

`.ForPostgreSql(q => q.SelectRaw("your Postgress query"))`

This method works in addition to the select so you can do a Select or SelectRaw AND the .ForPostgresSql (or other engine, there are more extension methods) and it combines both into a query.